# Path.Combine() returns unexpected results

Tags: c#, path

I'm trying to create a path using `Path.Combine()` but I am getting unexpected results.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace PathCombine_Delete
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string destination = "D:\\Directory";
            string destination02 = "it";
            string path = "L:\\MyFile.pdf";
            string sourcefolder = "L:\\";//In other instances, it could be L:\\SomeFolder\AndMayBeAnotherFolder
            string replacedDetails = path.Replace(sourcefolder + "\\", "");

            string result = Path.Combine(destination, destination02, replacedDetails);

            Console.WriteLine(result);
            Console.ReadKey();//Keep it on screen
        }
    }
}
```

I would expect the result `D:\\Directory\it\MyFile.pdf` but instead, I get `L:\MyFile.pdf`

I can't see why? I admit it's late in the evening here, but still, I've used [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991142%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) many times, and since .NET 4.0 it allows the string param to be passed. However, it appears to be ignoring the first 2 and only reading the last.

Comment: It probably only uses the last available root node.

Comment: Can you explain, preferably given some example input and output, what this code is supposed to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the error

```
 string replacedDetails = path.Replace(sourcefolder + "\\" , "");
```

You are adding another backslash and nothing is found to be replaced.
Removing the added backslash gives  the correct string to search for and replace

```
 string replacedDetails = path.Replace(sourcefolder , "");
```

however you could avoid all that replace stuff and intermediate variables just with

```
 string result = Path.Combine(destination, destination02, Path.GetFileName(path));
```

Comment: Well, you're right, but I still don't get it. I added a watch to `string result = Path.Combine(destination, destination02, replacedDetails);` and hovered the mouse over each variable name, and each name was as expected. I don't see why the path was not combined

Comment: The representation of backslashes is misleading

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using:

```
  string replacedDetails = Path.GetFileName(path);
```

That will handle removing the source folder from the path without using string replacement, which isn't necessarily reliable if you're getting the `path` from elsewhere (eventually).

Answer (score 1):

Have you [read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd784047%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? Have you verified what you're passing to `Path.Combine()`? The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd784047%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says, and I quote:

> *path1* should be an absolute path (for example, "d:\archives" or "\archives\public").
>   If *path2* or *path3* is also an absolute path, the combine operation discards all
>   previously combined paths and resets to that absolute path.

That should hint at the problem.

Comment: Yes, I did read it (I even linked to it in my post), but this didn't get absorbed... However, I thought because of the string replacement function I wasn't passing an absolute path. I was passing `L:\\MyFile.pdf.Replace(L:\\, "")` which made `MyFile.pdf`.  I now understand, so thank you